# Failed verification in Firebase with custom domain

Tags: firebase-authentication, dns, firebase-hosting, squarespace

I have an Imgur link below that shows images of the steps I've taken to set up DNS Settings on a SquareSpace site to get a Firebase custom domain set up. It keeps getting rejected for some reason.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Op4u.jpg

The first image shows the rejection from Firebase verification team:
[image]

The second image shows the domain as I entered it in the 'requesting to get verified' process:
[image]

The third image shows the DNS changes to make to my SquareSpace site:
[image]

The fifth image shows the DNS custom record entries I added in DNS Settings on SquareSpace:

[image]

No idea why I wouldn't be verified after adding these entries. Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: It says it may take up to 48 hours to verify. Have you tried waiting that long?

Comment: @kimbo Yes, I've tried submitting twice. Also, if it makes a difference my domain is in the format of www.my-domain.com.....I was thinking maybe the dash in the domain might be messing it up?

Comment: Was this solved?